# PHP: Fetching data from selected value on checkbox to create PDF

Tags: php, html, pdf, pdf-generation

It is my first time to debug other programmers work so I am kinda lost in its codes, anyway this is just the last simple thing I need to accomplish in this system. I already created the search page and all I need now is to create a function how to print the selected values in the checkbox.

I already created a function for creating pdf.

**Controller**

```
public function create_pdf_certificate($acctNo,$certReason,$dlCertType)
{
    $this->load->model('model_access','access');
    //$this->access->check_login();
    //$this->access->check_print_access();

    $this->load->model('model_account','account');
    $this->load->model('model_admin','admin');
    $this->load->model('model_constants','constants');
    $this->load->helper('to_pdf');
    $this->load->helper('file');

    $acctNo = str_replace("%7C","|",$acctNo);

    $data['accounts']   = $this->account->get_account($acctNo);
    $data['cert']       = $this->admin->get_treasury_dept_info();
    $data['clientName'] = $data['accounts'][0]->clientName;
    $data['certReason'] = $certReason;

    if($dlCertType == 'INDICORP')
        $html       = $this->load->view('pdf_download/indicorp', $data, true);
                    //$this->load->view('pdf_download/indicorp', $data);
    elseif($dlCertType == 'AUDIT')
    {
        $data['audit']  = $this->admin->get_audit_partner_info();
        $html           = $this->load->view('pdf_download/audit', $data, true);
                        //$this->load->view('pdf_download/audit', $data);
    }
    else
        $html       = $this->load->view('pdf_download/summary', $data, true);
                    //$this->load->view('pdf_download/summary', $data);

    $filename   = 'account'.date('mdY');

    create_pdf($html,$filename.time(), true);
}
```

and here is my **MODEL**

```
        if(count($res) > 0)
    {
        $i = 1;
        foreach($res as $row)
        {

                        $output['aaData'][] = array(
                                "<input type='checkbox' name='checkbox".$i."' id='checkbox".$i."' value='".$row->clientId."' />",
                                $row->clientName,
                                $row->product,
                                $row->accountNo,
                                $row->valueDate,
                                $row->maturityDate,
                                $row->ccy,
                                $row->principal,
                                $row->interestRate,
                                $row->maturityAmt
                                );
         $i++;
        }
    }
    //print_r($output);
    //return $output;
    return json_encode( $output );
```

Here is my view codes, I have this fieldset that also select the certificate type that I want to use a template.

```
    <fieldset style="width:990px;" >
    <div>
        <table id="searchTable" class="tableHeader" border="1" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>SELECT</th>
                    <th>CLIENT</th>
                    <th>PROD TYPE</th>
                    <th>REF ACCNT NO.</th>
                    <th>VALUE DATE</th>
                    <th>MATURITY DATE</th>
                    <th>CCY</th>
                    <th>PRINCIPAL</th>
                    <th>RATE (%)</th>
                    <th>MATURITY AMNT</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody style="color: black" class="tableRow">
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {


                $('#searchTable').dataTable( {
                            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                            "bAutoWidth": false,
                            "bProcessing": true,
                            "bServerSide": true,
                            "sAjaxSource": "<?php echo site_url() ?>/search/get_account",
                            "sServerMethod": "GET",
                            "fnServerData": function ( sSource, aoData, fnCallback ) 

                    {
                        aoData.push( { "name": "txtClient",     "value": "<?php echo $_POST["txtClient"]; ?>" } );
                        aoData.push( { "name": "txtAccntNo",    "value": "<?php echo $_POST["txtAccntNo"]; ?>" } );
                        aoData.push( { "name": "txtGrpAcctName","value": "<?php echo $_POST["txtGrpAcctName"]; ?>" } );
                        aoData.push( { "name": "txtDate",       "value": "<?php echo $_POST["txtDate"]; ?>" } );



                        $.getJSON( sSource, aoData, function (json) 
                        {
                            fnCallback(json)
                        } );
                    },
                    "aoColumns": [ 
                                  { "sClass": "centerAligned"   , "bSortable" : false }, //SELECT
                                  { "sClass": "centerAligned"   , "bSortable" : false }, //CLIENT
                                  { "sClass": "centerAligned"   , "bSortable" : false }, //PROD TYPE
                                  { "sClass": "centerAligned"   , "bSortable" : false }, //REF ACCNT NO.
                                  { "sClass": "centerAligned"   , "bSortable" : false }, //VALUE DATE
                                  { "sClass": "centerAligned"   , "bSortable" : false }, //MATURITY DATE
                                  { "sClass": "centerAligned"   , "bSortable" : false }, //CCY
                                  { "sClass": "leftAligned"     , "bSortable" : false }, //PRINCIPAL
                                  { "sClass": "leftAligned"     , "bSortable" : false }, //RATE (%)
                                  { "sClass": "leftAligned"     , "bSortable" : false }, //MATURITY AMNT
                                  ]
                } );
            } );
        </script>                       
    </div>
    <hr/>
    <table class="formTable" cellspacing="0" align="center">
        <tr>
            <td class="label" width="200px">Reason: <span class="required">*</span></td>
            <td class="field" width="300px"><?php echo form_textarea($formCertReason); ?></td>
            <td class="field">
                <hr style="visibility: hidden"/>
                <div class="btnHolder">
                  <a id="colDownloadBtn" href="#" onclick="Account.checkRequiredFields();"> <?php echo $_POST['certType']; ?>
                    <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>public/images/form/btn_download_cert.gif" style="cursor: pointer;" />
                  </a>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table> 
</fieldset>
```

Comment: What library is the project written in? The model shown above looks like it's generating the html for the inpute field which would normally be reserved for the view. The value would usually be returned (and captured) by using a $_POST['checkbox1'] or $_GET['checkbox1']. In some libraries like CodeIgniter you have built in methods that you're supposed to use.

Comment: Yes I updated my codes to include the view part, can you please check it again? thank you!